# C# .NET Entity Framework multi-tenant best practice

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Consider the following code segment:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   public DatabaseContext(String connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {            
   }
}

public class ContextNameDatabaseContext : DatabaseContext
{
   public ContextNameDatabaseContext(String connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {
   }
}
```

Would one say it is best practice when building the back-end for a multi-tenant solution where each client has its own database and maintain the data state until a user logs out / off?

Developer using these classes in this instance will need to be aware and careful as to when and how the classes are being used where the 'DatabaseContext' class acts as a base to the 'ContextNameDatabaseContext' class.

Please advise on any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: What practice you mean exactly? Passing different connection strings to constructor?

Comment: The key here is not only to have different connection strings injected to the 'DbContext' base class but when a user logs in, maintain that connection until a user logs out / off.

Comment: And how code you provided solves this?

Comment: When in the process you know the connection string for the database, is it before login or after login. how are you storing the connection strings?

Comment: @Coding: 

After login because only then would the credentials be verified.

Connection strings are stored in a database table.

Comment: I think `multi-tenant` is to use same database but to segregate the clients by their profile or subscription, what you need is to make a table for the connection strings and link the customer/ client to the corresponding connection string and on each request you read the corresponding connection string based on the client id.

Comment: @Evk: 

One solution to this problem may be the following:

private static Lazy<ContextNameDatabaseContext> _dbContext = new Lazy<ContextNameDatabaseContext>(() => new ContextNameDatabaseContext(connectionString));
        public static ContextNameDatabaseContext DBContext
        {
            get { return _dbContext.Value; }
        }

... this will ensure only one instant of the ContextNameDatabaseContext class is initialized but that is one way of looking to solve this problem.

Comment: @Monah:

Arguably you are correct in your scenario because multi-tenant is the idea where a single software solution shares a common access point which in your case the common access point is one database (same database). 

However in my instance I would like to have a common access point at a different level which in my case is the orm.

Comment: you can make a shared database that contains a table in which contains ( ClientId, ConnectionString) , on each request you  can read from this table the client's connection string, for more security, you might also store the connection string as encrypted string.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to keep all the database connection strings as parameters in the database. However you have to assure that its encrypted.

Then at your DB layer you can pass the connection as parameter in plain text after decrypting and constructing your connection string accordingly:

```
public class MyDatabase: DbContext
{
    public MyDatabase(string connString)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;
    }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
}
```

You can also use `IOptions` if you are using .NET Core to inject the connection string as a dependency.

Comment: Not familiar with the IOptions interface, will definitely read up on it.